# C# return a jump statement from a function

Tags: c#, function, return

As all coders I hate repeated blocks of code, but as a C++ dev I really want the null checks as it has been burnt into me meaning a have a lot of blocks that look like

```
if(object == null)
{
    //For loops
    continue;

    //To check function inputs/creation
    return; //maybe with a value
}
```

I know I could put a try/catch around everything, but I really don't like that style of coding

Is there a way to replace the null check block with a generic function. Something like

```
jumpstatement CheckNull<T>(T thingToCheck)
{
    if(thingToCheck == null)
    {
        return continue;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Then in the actual code instead of the old repeated blocks I'd have just the function (padded out as requested)

```
for(int i = 0; i < myCollection.Count; i++){
    //Function forces a "continue;" call if null
    CheckNull(myCollection[i]);

    //Do some stuff with myCollection[i]
}
```

The closest thing I could see was talking about code snippits or inline functions but I really don't think that's what I want.

Comment: This is not possible. Try to make use of [null conditional operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-6#null-conditional-operators) instead.

Comment: In some situations, [Null object pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_object_pattern) can be useful.

Comment: Generally I don't code in that style (either when I was a C++ dev in the nineties or in C# since it was released in the naughts). Generally, I tend to invert the null check and include the main body of code within the scope if the `if`. You may also find that the null conditional operators (`?.` and `?[]`) and null coalescing operators (`??` and in C# 8 `??=`) may greatly reduce your need for this pattern.

Comment: You'll have to put the code surrounding `CheckNull(someObject)` into your example so that we know where you want execution to flow to in the event of a null.  `continue` is only relevant in a `while`, `do`, `for`, or `foreach`, but you do not have one surrounding your `CheckNull` example.  Can you pad it out to demonstrate the control flow that you desire?

Comment: It's any general code where a null check would return early, weather it's a loop that would continue or a function that would drop out. 
The whole idea of return early is flat level code rather than nested statements which makes code significantly easier to read. So I know I could just keep nesting, but it's not the solution I'm looking for

Comment: I think you should look at [yield](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/yield). This will help you to gracefully handle the return from a loop with different values.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov This actually looks pretty cool. I need to read a bit more to wrap my head around how to use it, but definitely looks like it could make smaller and more readable code if used correctly

Answer (score 2):

I don't think what you want to do here is possible. Basically, you want to be able to call a function which affects control flow in the function *calling* it (e.g. you want to be able to return from the *calling* function from your function). This is not possible with a normal function.

This sort of thing *is* possible in C/C++ using function-like macros, and in several other languages which support "real" macros. Unfortunately, C# does not have macros, so this sort of thing can't be done in the way you want.

Comment: Yes, in C++ I'd write a macro function and be done; which is exactly what I want. Although when I wrote a question to that affect I got "Use snippits" and marked as duplicate...

Comment: The Nemerle language, similar to C#, has macros. Microsoft is gradually moving features from Nemerle to C#, but it hasn't reached macros yet. Maybe in C# 10 we will finally wait for them... @Justin

Answer (score -1):

C# 8 has a new feature called [`nullable reference types`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-reference-types) that's even better. You add a few annotations here and there, and then the compiler can handle a lot of this for you. You get to just write the code you want to write, without worrying a reference might accidentally be `null`. It takes some getting used to, but it's pretty cool once you've mastered the concept.

Aside from that, you can't return an arbitrary jump or goto... but you *can* return a **[`delegate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/delegates/)**. This is similar to C/C++ function pointer. You can theoretically use this to turn this proposed call:

```
CheckNull(someObject);
```

into this:

```
CheckNull(someObject)();
```

where the return value of `CheckNull()` is a method you want to call. But more practically, it would probably look more like this:

```
CheckNull(someObject, o => {
   //Do something with someObject here, where you can be **sure** someObject is not null
});
```

You could even embed a [`lock`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement) into your method to keep things more thread-safe.

```
public void CheckNull<T>(T target, Action<T> action)
{
    if (target is object)
    {   //naive implementation -- potential thread race between these two lines
        // ... but it does narrow the race to JUST those two lines, regardless of how much work is hidden in the action.
        lock(target)
        {
           action(target);
        }
    }
}
```

The other thing you can do is use `Where()` operation. So if you have an array like this

```
object[] items = new object[100];  
FillArray(items);
```

You can write code like this loop over only the items that are not null:

```
foreach(var item in items.Where(i => i is object))
{
   //item will not be null, as long as you're in a single thread. Otherwise, lock on something first.
}
```

Comment: Thats does not do what OP wants... He wants to have a continue in the null check method. He could have basicall have done a `if(CheckNull(someObject)) continue;` but he didn't... Indicating that don't want to do that. Besides... Nullable reference types wont help him here, since he wants someObject to be null.